# Do I need an appostile when providing documents for a Danish short-term visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, paperwork, denmark

Hi I am an Indian citizen and I would like to visit Aarhus University, Denmark for a month in this summer. I have an invitation letter from them saying that they are providing me travel and local hospitality during my stay. I would like to take my family (my wife and a year old daughter). For my wife we will apply for a dependant visa. I have sufficient financial proof to support their travel and stay. My passport has my wife's name endorsed but in her passport my name is not endorsed. We have a marriage certificate but its not appostiled by the Ministry of External Affairs. Again my daughter's passport has our names endorsed but her birth certificate is not appostiled. Will these documents be enough to get our visas? Also, does my one year old daughter need a ticket to travel ?

Comment: What was the question? Are you asking if documents need an apostille?

Comment: ya, you are right. Is apostille is necessary in this case or my wife's name in my passport is enough to get a visa.

Comment: Based upon what you wrote you should get the marriage certificate and the birth certificate apostilled.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Denmark](http://um.dk/en/travel-and-residence/legalisation/countries-outside-the-apostille-convention/apostille-countries/), India is a party to the Apostille convention. You would therefore need to receive an apostille at the Indian Ministry of Foreign Affairs before submitting your documents.